# How do I install drivers for AMD graphics card on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

So I've just downloaded Ubuntu (using it as a dual-boot) on my machine - a 6800 graphics card and 5900x processor. Although the install was successful, the screen is very laggy/unresponsive (mouse is slow/sluggish).

I've heard you don't need to install proprietary drivers, but it just feels like I'm running on integrated graphics and that it's somehow not picking up my GPU. I've tried installing the amd-gpu-pro drivers but keep getting this same error. I've also noticed that it won't let me change my resolution or refresh rate in settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried-

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

trying to install amdgpu-pro

[image: module build failed and dependency problem]

Answer (score 0):

A very impotant part in setting up your pc is making sure you plug the display cable into your graphics card. Because the Ryzen 5900X is not Vega accellerated, you can get this kind of issues if you got your DisplayPort plugged into the motherboard.